# What is cross platform mobile development and How it will achieve?

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I am developed native mobile apps in Android but I want run my application on multiple platform How can do it. I heard About PhoneGap is good for cross platform mobile development, what language PhoneGap used for developing mobile apps, can I develop "Hybrid Apps" In Phonegap, How many days it will take to learn.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

You can develop hybrid apps in PhoneGap. PhoneGap applications are primarily written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

The number of days it will take to learn is not a number anyone can give you. It will depend on your current skill set, coding experience and learning ability.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com) for developing cross-platform mobile applications. I myself have a great experience from the industrial project that I developed with MoSyncin which I used rich native user interface, Bluetooth/Wi-Fi communication for real-time data, and much more.

C, C++, HTML5, JavaScript, CSS are used while developing with MoSync. For more points check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750459/whats-idea-about-mosync/14234182#14234182) and their website for finding [feature/platform support](http://www.mosync.com/widepage/feature-platform-support).